# Why is the `unary_` prefix needed in scala?

Tags: scala

Beginner Scala question, but I couldn't find the answer on here.

Similar to overloading in C++, I would expect the compiler can tell the difference between a method called `-` which takes one parameter (with the same type as the class) and the unary version of `-` which takes no parameters, so why is `unary_` needed?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `unary_` prefix for *unary prefix operators* is a bit misleading: it's more about the *prefix* part than the *unary* part. You need some way to distinguish

```
!foo // unary prefix !
```

from

```
foo! // unary postfix !
```

Remember: Scala doesn't actually have operators. There are two ways to call a method, either with a `.` or with whitespace:

```
foo.bar(1, "two")
foo bar(1, "two")
```

And when you have a single argument, you can leave off the parentheses:

```
foo plus(1)
foo plus 1
```

Lastly, (almost) *any* character is legal in an identifier:

```
foo plus 1
foo + 1
```

Now it *looks* like Scala has a binary infix `+` operator, but it actually doesn't. It's just a normal method called with normal method calling syntax.

What I said above isn't *fully* true, however. If Scala didn't have support for operators and it all was just normal method calling, then

```
2 + 3 * 4
```

would evaluate to 20 (like it does in Smalltalk, Self and Newspeak for example) instead of 14. So, there is a *little* bit of support for operators in Scala (two little bits, actually). When a method is called with whitespace (so-called "operator syntax") instead of the `.`, and that method starts with an operator character, then Scala will respect operator precedence.

And the other little bit of operator support is that there are some operators that you would *like* to have, but that cannot be easily expressed as a method call. It works fine for binary infix operators and unary postfix operators:

```
foo op bar // same as:
foo.op(bar)

foo op     // same as:
foo.op
```

But not for prefix or "around-fix" operators:

```
!foo
foo(bar)
```

So, there are a couple of special syntactic sugar translation rules:

```
!foo
foo.unary_!
// same for +, - and ~

foo(bar)
foo.apply(bar)

foo(bar) = 1
foo.update(bar, 1)

foo += 1
foo.+=(1) // but if this doesn't compile, then the compiler will also try
foo = foo.+(1)
```

And the reason why there needs to be an underscore between the alphanumeric and the "operator" part in a method name is because you wouldn't know whether

```
foo!
```

means

```
foo.!
```

or

```
this.foo!
```

Thus, `foo!` as a method name is illegal, it needs to be called `foo_!`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and additional insight :)

Comment: Since this answer seems to gather some attention: is there a a bit of method calling syntax sugar I am missing?

Comment: "When a method is called with whitespace (so-called "operator syntax") instead of the ., and that method starts with an operator character, then Scala will respect operator precedence." @jhabbott watch this: scala> 2.+3.*4
res10: Double = 14.0

Comment: @liango: You are using operator syntax in that case. It is being interpreted as `(2.) + (3.) * (4)`. You should get a deprecation warning, though; float literals without decimals are deprecated and will be removed in later versions.

Answer (score 9):

Because in scala it is totally fine to create a method named `-`, that takes no arguments. How would you distinguish between a normal and a unary method? For example `!` has a totally different meaning as unary, than as post fix operator.

Comment: So you can have `!x` and `x!` both called just `!` and taking no additional parameters and the compiler will know it's two different functions? Also it will know which one to call because it's before or after the object?

Comment: Jörg W Mittag explains in a little more detail, what I wanted to say with my answer ;-)

Comment: Yeah thanks - you both got upvotes :) I'm just learning and some things are tricky to understand when you don't know about all the other things yet.