# Scala custom operator (example abs)

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, operators

I know that scala allows overloading for it's default operators (+, - ! etc.) . Is it possible to define custom operators and make something like the |.| operator so that | -3| that evaluates to 3. Or defining an operator like ++++ so that a ++++ b equals a+3*b?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at [scala operators documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/operators.html).

You can easily make the ++++ operator but not the |.| operator.

Operators in scala are just functions with non alphanumeric name. Since scala also support call a.f(b) as a f b then you can achieve the first behavior. For example:

```
case class A(v: Int) {
  def ++++(b: A): A = A(v + 3 * b.v)
}

val a = A(1)
val b = A(2)
a ++++ b
>> A(7)
a.++++(b) // just another way of doing the exact same call
```

If you want to add this to integer you would simply create an implicit class to add it.

Another option is to prefix the operator for example consider doing -a to get the negative. There is no "first element" to apply the - to, instead - is applied to a (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644988/why-is-the-unary-prefix-needed-in-scala)).

For example:

```
case class A(v: Int) {
  def unary_!(): Int = -v
}
val a = A(3)
!a
>> -3
```

Doing |.| has two issues: First there are two parts to the operator, i.e. it is split. The second is the use of |

In order to do a two part operator (say !.!) you would probably want to generate some private type and return it from one ! and then use it as the input for the other to return the output type.

The second issue is the use of | which is an illegal character. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656937/valid-identifier-characters-in-scala) for a list of legal characters

Comment: `|` is legal though and it's listed as legal in the answer you've linked.

Comment: You are correct, it appears as legal from the answer, however, that specific character doesn't seem to work (at least in the REPL) There must be another limitation I missed.

Comment: Hm, for me it works normally as a method: `class A {
  def |(int: Int) = int * 2;
  def ||(int: Int) = int * 3;
  def |||(int: Int) = int * 4
}; new A || 2 // returns 6`. It doesn't work as `unary_|` and I believe only `unary_-` and `unary_!` are supported as prefix operators.

Comment: The thing is that the OP asked for `|x|` having `|` as delimiter. It still can be done but doesn't will be clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

An example to extend [@assaf-mendelson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782514/187261) answer

```
case class Abs(a: Int) {
  def !(): Int = a.abs
}

implicit def toAbs(a: Int) = new {
  def unary_! : Abs = Abs(a)
}
```

then

```
> val a = -3
a: Int = -3

> !a
res0: Abs = Abs(-3)

> !a!
res1: Int = 3

> val b = 12
b: Int = 12

> !b!
res2: Int = 12

> (!a!) + (!b!)
res3: Int = 15
```

We cannot implement abs as `|a|` because `unary_` works only with `!`, `~`, `+` and `-`

Comment: The code does not work, neither with Scala 3 nor with Scala 2 (3.1.3 and 2.11.12)